# Magento associate products highlighted red

Tags: magento

What's happening with the highlighted red background? I know that I am only allow to associate any combination of attributes that are not the same. But this clearly states that I only have one in each color and size.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top product has a duplicate (the third line) i.e. its Red and XXL.

The second product is duplicated on the last line i.e. it's Flint Grey and XL.

You should only be allowed one product per unique combination of configurable attributes - did this happen by an integration script like Magmi? If so you will need to start checking for pre-existing combinations, although it looks like the main issue here is that you have identical products with different SKUs (business nightmare?)